# Use SOCKS5 proxy from the Debian installer

Tags: debian, apt, socks

I need to be able to use SOCKS5 proxy from the Debian installer. The proxy is provided by SSH client, quick and easy.

It should be possible to do *after* installation is finished, as described [in this AskUbuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1117259):

```
Acquire::http::proxy "socks5h://server:port";
```

However, if I type such a thing when Debian installer asks for a proxy, installer logs an error:

```
Error parsing proxy URL socks5h://[my-server-name]:[port]/: Unsupported scheme 'socks5h'.
```

It's obvious it doesn't like this syntax.

So, is it possible at all, for example, using a preseed file (which it will eventually use)?

---

**Update:** The syntax suggested in AskUbuntu answer doesn't work in Debian. Does it need some plugin or something like that? Is it possible to make it work in Debian?